# How can I omit records when returning a table in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a problem when I try to execute a function where, depending on the result of another function, it returns a record or not. What I want to do is that when the function ("function_typecar" in the example) returns 1 as a result, it returns the record, otherwise no. The problem is when the condition is not met. It repeats the same record until there is one that meets the condition again. Is there a way to skip returning the records when the condition is not met? I leave an example of this situation

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema.function_test
  RETURNS TABLE(id_r INTEGER, name_r CHARACTER VARYING, year_r INTEGER) AS
$BODY$
  
DECLARE 
    sql_record RECORD;
    type_car INTEGER;
BEGIN  
    SELECT id, name, year
    FROM car


    FOR sql_record IN
        SELECT id, name, year
        FROM car
    LOOP
        SELECT type INTO type_car FROM function_typecar(sql_record.id);

        IF type_car = 1 THEN
            id_r := sql_record.id;
            name_r := sql_record.name;
            year_r := sql_record.year;          

        END IF;

        RETURN NEXT;

    END LOOP;
END; $BODY$
```

This is the result that I want to avoid and that only brings me those that meet the IF condition:

[image]

Comment: `IF type_car = 1 THEN ... ELSE id_r := NULL; ...`. Then `select from function_test() where id_r IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: The only problem with this is that the function that I put is an example (sorry for not clarifying). Actually within that IF other functions are executed which take more time and the original function brings about 3000 records so the time it takes to execute the function is a lot. What I want is to avoid the execution of these functions if the "IF" condition is not met

Comment: Department of second thoughts: `IF type_car = 1 THEN ...  RETURN NEXT;  END IF;`

Comment: You don't need a loop for this, just use the function in the query where you select the car, and a where condition WHERE type_car - 1

Comment: putting the "return next " inside the "if" worked. thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work, without a LOOP and in plain SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_test()
  RETURNS TABLE(id_r INTEGER, name_r CHARACTER VARYING, year_r INTEGER)
LANGUAGE SQL 
    AS
$BODY$
    SELECT  id, name, year
    FROM car
            JOIN function_typecar(id) ON type = 1;
$BODY$;
```

Comment: Or even simpler, `WHERE function_typecar(id).type = 1`